# Conditional Expectation - throwing dice

Tags: probability

> **Question**: A fair die is rolled repeatedly. Let X and Y denote,
>   respectively, the number of rolls necessary to obtain a 6 and a 5. For
>   this question you may find it helpful tp recall how to derive a
>   formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$ from the geometric series
>   forumla.
>
> Find
>
> a) E(X);
>
> b) E[X|Y = 1];

So for a), this is a geometric distribution so $E[X] = 6$.

However I am kind of unsure how to go about doing b). So the formula for a discrete conditional expectation is 
$$E[X|y=y] = \sum_x xP\{X=x|Y=y\}$$

To find $E[X|Y=1]$ is it just:

$ (1)P\{X=1|Y=1\} + (2)P\{X=2|Y=1\} + (3)P\{X=3|Y=1\} + (4)P\{X=4|Y=1\} + (5)P\{X=5|Y=1\} + (6)P\{X=6|Y=1\} $

But then how do I compute $P\{X=1|Y=1\}$? And where does the geometric series come into play here?

Comment: This is just a single string of rolls, yes?  So if the first roll gets a $5$ then it can't also get a $6$.

Comment: $X|Y=1\sim 1+X$.

Comment: $P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X) P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}$ may be helpful

Comment: @Rellek I doubt that. For $X$ and $Y$ random variables, what would be $P(X\cap Y)$, say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$The best way to get this is to notice that $X\sim \text{Geom}(p = 1/6)$ on $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, and in particular $$X|Y = 1 \overset d= 1+X$$
as A.S. commented. This means
$$E[X|Y=1] = E[1+X] = 1+6 = 7.$$

There are a number of other ways to get this. To do it your way, then
$$P(X = k|Y = 1)$$
means that I tell you that you have taken one turn and got a 5, what is the probability of getting the first six on roll $k$.

So,

1. $P(X= 1|Y = 1) = 0$
2. $P(X =2|Y = 1) = 1/6$
3. Consider $P(X = 3|Y = 1)$. In other words,
   \begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
   \text{Trial}&1&2&3\\\hline
   \text{Outcome}&5&\text F&6\\\hline
   \text{Chance}& 1 &\dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6}
   \end{array}
   where $\text F$ means not rolling a six. Since, it is given that $Y=1$, the chance that it happens is $1$. Hence
   $$P(X = 3|Y = 1) = (5/6)(1/6).$$
4. Consider $P(X = 4|Y = 1)$. In other words,
   \begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c}
   \text{Trial}&1&2&3&4\\\hline
   \text{Outcome}&5&\text F& \text F &6\\\hline
   \text{Chance}& 1 &\dfrac{5}{6}&\dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6}
   \end{array}
   Hence $P(X = 4|Y = 1) = (5/6)^2(1/6)$,

and in general
$$P(X = k|Y = 1) = (5/6)^{k-2}(1/6),$$
for $k\geq 2, 0$ otherwise.
Thus
$$E[X|Y=1] = \sum_{k = 2}^\infty kP(X = k|Y=1) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty k(5/6)^{k-2}(1/6).$$
But we can simplify our work if we play around a little.
\begin{align*}
E[X|Y = 1]&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty kP(X=k|Y=1)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-2}p\\
&=\frac{1}{1-p}\left[\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}p\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{1-p}\left[-p+\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}p\right]\tag 1\\
&=\frac{1}{1-p}\left[-p+E[X]\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{5/6}\left[-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{1/6}\right]\\
&=7,
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$, I recognize that the series is simply the expectation of a geometric distribution with $p = 1/6$ on $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$. Also, at $(1)$ you can use the series they gave you if you pull out $p$ from the series. I didn't bother. I like my way better.

Comment: @probablyne can you explain how you derived $P(X=1|Y=1)=0$,
$P(X=2|Y=1)=1/6$, and 
$P(X=3|Y=1)=(5/6)(1/6)$? I can see why the probability is 0 in the first one. But not for the second and third cases.

Comment: And why do we have $k-2$? I thought that its $k-1$ for geometric because we have have $k$ trials, $k-1$ are failures and the kth trail is the successes.

Comment: I tell you that you got a 5 on the first roll. What is the probability you get a six on the second roll?

Comment: Yes, I am asking, and waiting for you to reply.

Comment: the probability of rolling 5 is 1/6. and the probability of rolling 6 is 1/6. But I'm not sure what to think next?

Comment: I tell you that you got a five on the first roll. What is the probability that you get the first six on the third roll?

Comment: Could you talk me through how to figure this out? I'm still scratching my head at your questions

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot

Comment: @karambit  Great. Consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.

Comment: actually isn't there a mistake in the line that you marked $(1)$? In the brackets part, how do you have $-p$? shouldn't it be $-(2(1-p)(1/6))$?

Comment: It is not a mistake. Try to think of why it works. Note that the bounds of the summation changed.

Comment: Think about it and let me know if you still don't get it.

Comment: wait, we subtract $k =1$, $(1)(1−p)^0p = p$

Comment: I think you get it. We add and subtract $p$ so that we can change the bounds of the summation and notice that the series become $E[X]$.